# PHP 'include' Navigation automatically add '../' when used in subfolders

Tags: php, html, include, navigation

I have spent days searching the solution to this question and there have been many given already in the past years but I still can't get my head around it. I am a beginner in PHP so any help is appreciated.

I am not sure if there's a common solution that will work with the WAMP localhost AND the online website at the same time.

My `navMain.php` file is the `/includes` folder.

Lets say I have `index.php` and `contact.php` in the root folder (`wamp/www/SITENAME/` on the PC and `httpdocs/` on the server). I also will have `books.php` in the `/media` folder.

What code do I created in the `navMain.php` file so that when `index.php` reads it its resulting navigation links to `contact.php` as `<a href="contact.php">` but when `books.php` reads it it's `<a href="../contact.php">` or something more foolproof?

I found solutions like `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` but still not sure if that's meant for questions like mine and supposed to be put in the `navMain.php` file or if it's to properly link to the `navMain.php` file when used in the 'include' command in files like `index.php`.

Also, when I tried the solutions I found, I don't know how to make it work well on the localhost AND/OR the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use absolute paths, paths that start with `/`.

Absolute paths always work no matter the current url.

Comment: I thought I had to do some further reading and find complicated codes but seems like u meant what you typed. So thanks! But then, mind telling what the needs is for the codes like ABSPATH? I am still confused.
so instead of `index.php` I have named it to `/index.php`for the website and `/sitename/index.php` for the localhost. That's correct? It works so far but I don't get the point of SERVER and __FILE__ and such codes.

Comment: I don't see the relation with `$_SERVER` or `$_FILES`. **Just start all urls with `/`, where `/` represents the http root**. I mean it :D Personally, i just code the url once in a config file and never hardcode them again, my favorite framework provides a function to generate absolute urls everywhere I need, using that same config. This allows more usable and changeable urls without having to re-write all templates etc ... If you feel like hacking some cool code, I recommend that you try some frameworks - most of them have quick and easy tutorials. Even Rails (ruby) or Django (python).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in an included file maybe...

Put your path logic with the '`$root_path =` ' variable - this way if you are testing on or offline it is going to work

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.mydomain.com'){ // put in here your live domain name - echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to ensure its correct
    // this is your online server
    $root_path = "/hello";
}else{
    // this is your offline test environment
    $root_path = "local/hello/";
}
```

then in your page...

```
<a href="<?php echo $root_path;?>/file.php">Link</a>
```